# What is the fastest way to write all sectors on a drive?

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, dd

The goal in my case is not to securely erase data, but simply to force sector reallocation by the drives firmware.

I have a drive that has had a few file corruptions. It seems to be due to getting very hot at some point in the past, the max reported temperature is 99C ! I've recovered as much data from it as I can with ntfsclone --rescue and mounted the image.

The reallocated sector count is zero but the current pending sector count is 233.

If I write to the sectors then they will either be remapped or have their status restored , I'm wondering which is faster badblocks -w or dd or something else?

I've observed with iotop that badblocks is writing at about 17Mb/s which I don't think is very fast for this drive. dd from /dev/zero gives about 24Mb/s but it pauses frequently and the average seems about 13.5Mb/s, again seems too slow for this drive. At this rate it would take a whole day and night to zero the drive.

Perhaps I'm not using dd correctly and there are betters ways to make a large sequential write.

Comment: I added a block size argument to dd "bs=1m" and this seems to be giving a steady value of 30Mb/s which is better.

Comment: try 4 or 8mb. my hunch is setting it to be whatever the drive's cache size is would be optimal.

Comment: Agree w/bs=cache size, but are you trying to restore this drive for use? Are you doing this to recover data, or to prepare the disk for reuse? It sounds like this disk is ready for the bin.

Comment: Try `ddrescue`.

Comment: dd rescue looks great, but in this case I used ntfsclone because it's more space efficient and I don't quite have enough space for the full partition, but I do have enough space for the data. ntfsclone --rescue is similar

Comment: I was using conv=sync which I read somewhere on a page about zeroing, it hits the performance massively. taking this option out brought the performance back to a more expected level of around 80MB/s

Comment: Stepping back a little I would consider this drive unreliable and I would personally replace it.  You should also find out _why_ it gets so hot and if it explains the data corruptions so the replacement drive does not develop the same symptoms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your goal is to really **"zero"** the drive, then I bet the fastest you can get is to issue a low-level *secure erase* command using `hdparm` (see [here](http://tinyapps.org/docs/wipe_drives_hdparm.html) for step-by-step instructions).

Note two things:

- As `hdparm` manpage vividly states, the operation is "DANGEROUS".
- On the other hand, it *may* also repair bad blocks.

Comment: Of course, if the data on the device is already discounted as "lost", the low level erase isn't going to be able to do much more harm...

Comment: Actually the goal is simply to get the drives firmware to reallocate or reinstate the pending sectors. I believe the drive might be stable but lost some data when it got hot at some stage

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz that link is great. hdparm really has some amazing features. I had no idea a firmware based secure erase even existed, you can even reset the whole device and re write over reallocated sectors!

Comment: "As hdparm manpage vividly states, the operation is "DANGEROUS"." Why?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver: That's a good question, actually. In short, there are several possible corner cases that may result in drive damage. Here are some considerations that come to my mind: a) the drive's firmware will be operating in a special mode for extended period of time, performing low-level operations - what if your system crashes in that period? b) You have limited possibilities of monitoring the actual state of the drive. c) Either the drive's firmware or your system's kernel can be faulty, each of which may lead to drive damage.